# Proof of Liouvilles theorem - $\sqrt{n}$ seems to pointlessly appear

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Evans p30 - Liouville's theorem.

Suppose $u:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ is harmonic and bounded. Then $u$ is constant.

Proof: Fix $x_0\in \Bbb R^n$, $r>0$ and apply the estimate on derivatives, that is:
$$\|D^\alpha u(x_0)\| \leq \frac{C_k}{r^{n+k}}\|u\|_{L^1(B(x_0,r))},$$ for each ball $B(x_0,r)\subset U$ and $|\alpha|=k$.

---

Here however he writes $$|Du(x_0)|\leq \frac{\sqrt{n} C_1}{r^{n+1}}\|u\|_{L^1(B(x_0,r))}\leq \frac{\sqrt{n}C_1\alpha(n)}{r}\|u\|_{L^\infty(\Bbb R^n)}\to 0$$ as $r\to\infty$.

**Why did he write the** $\sqrt{n}$?** It seems completely pointless (although it's true no doubt).

It seems not to alter the proof, but it makes me unsure that perhaps I am not understanding something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case $|\alpha| = k =1$, $D^\alpha$ is just a partial derivative, while $Du$ is the full vector of all partial derivatives. So if you know $|\partial_i u|\le C$ for each $i$, then  $$|Du|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |\partial_i u|^2\le nC^2$$ and thus $|Du| \le \sqrt n C$.

Comment: Of course! Thank you!